# Get calendar events from Exchange server (ews)?

Tags: delphi, exchange-server

How can I get events from a specific Exchange account using Delphi (without using Outlook)?

Comment: I believe you are looking for MAPI - http://www.imibo.com/imidev/delphi/les/index.html

Answer (score 6):

<strike>I'm doing it through [Exchange Web Services (EWS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) with SOAP XML calls. I [failed to get it to work](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=60150&tstart=0) using the [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) from the server (Delphi XE2), so now I'm doing it all through my own SOAP generation, using tools like [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for testing/debugging. This is all 'from the ground up', so a lot of work.</strike>

If you only need to get events it may be simpler than what I'm doing (full synchronization, already working on it for weeks).

If you can communicate through Outlook instead of communicating directly to Exchange (i.e. when running from a client machine) I can recommend [DevExpress Scheduler component](http://www.devexpress.com/products/vcl/ExScheduler/).

--- UPDATE 2 OKT 2023 ---

I no longer recommended this path:

*"On October 1, 2026, we will start blocking EWS requests from non-Microsoft apps to Exchange Online"*
Source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/retirement-of-exchange-web-services-in-exchange-online/ba-p/3924440

With this in mind, [MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is the (only) way to go.